# Get all namespaces within an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a deeply nested object: 
`{ a: { b: { c: 3 }, d: 4 } }`.

How to get all namespaces within this object?

So, I need to get:
`['a.b.c', 'a.d']`.

Comment: d is not inside a!

Comment: Recursive Object.keys() If a key is an object, get its keys as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can create recursive function using `for...in` loop.

```js
var obj = {a: {b: {c: 3} }, d: 4 }

function getKeys(data, prev) {
  var result = []
  for (var i in data) {
    var dot = prev.length ? '.' : '';
    if (typeof data[i] == 'object') result.push(...getKeys(data[i], prev + dot + i))
    else result.push(prev + dot + i)
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getKeys(obj, ''))
```

Instead of `for...in` loop you can use `Object.keys()` and `reduce()`.

```js
var obj = {a: {b: {c: 3} }, d: 4 }

function getKeys(data, prev) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce(function(r, e) {
    var dot = prev.length ? '.' : '';
    if (typeof data[e] == 'object') r.push(...getKeys(data[e], prev + dot + e))
    else r.push(prev + dot + e)
    return r;
  }, [])
}

console.log(getKeys(obj, ''))
```

Comment: If you use `var obj = {abc:1, d: 1}` with your function, you get the same result...

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado I forgot about dots, i think it work fine now.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var t = {a: {b: {c: 3} }, d: 4 };

path (t, '');

function path(t, sofar) {

  if (Object.keys(t).length === 0)
    console.log(sofar.substr(1));
  
  var keys = Object.keys(t);
  
  for (var i = 0 ; i < keys.length ; ++i) {
    path(t[keys[i]], sofar+'.'+keys[i]);
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a script in order to flatten the object and return the keys. You could also think to convert it to an array and use the default `flatten` of arrays. Here an example of flattening the object.

```js
var flattenObject = function(ob) {
     var toReturn = {};
     
     for (var i in ob) {
      if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
      
      if ((typeof ob[i]) == 'object') {
       var flatObject = flattenObject(ob[i]);
       for (var x in flatObject) {
        if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;
        
        toReturn[i + '.' + x] = flatObject[x];
       }
      } else {
       toReturn[i] = ob[i];
      }
     }
     return toReturn;
    };

    var obj = {a: {b: {c: 3} }, d: 4 }
    console.log(Object.keys(flattenObject(obj))); // ['a.b.c', 'd']
```

p.s. your object in the question has a mistake, or what you want is not what you are asking. d is at the same level of a, so you can't achieve "a.d", but "d"

Comment: It's `Object.keys`, lowercase k. Besides that, it doesn't log what you show in your answer. Convert this into a snippet, it's easier to check.

Comment: Hi @GerardoFurtado, thanks for the reply, changed it, I tried it in the console and it prints what I described...could you please tell me how to convert it to a snippet? sorry for the "newbie" question but I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Now it's correct. If you edit your answer, you'll gona see a icon like this: <> . It's the seventh from left. Click it, you can put your code in the JavaScript box.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks this is awesome! Everytime I was using jsfiddle to provide snippets but this is so much easier! thanks again :)

Comment: Beautiful. Do you see? People can instantly check that your code is working.

Comment: awesome ^_^ thanks again! you won't see anymore an answer by me without a code snippet :D
Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You could check the keys and iterate otherwise push the path to the result set.

```js
function getKeys(object) {
    function iter(o, p) {
        var keys = Object.keys(o);
        keys.length ?
            keys.forEach(function (k) { iter(o[k], p.concat(k)); }):
            result.push(p.join('.'));
    }
    var result = [];
    iter(object, []);
    return result;
}

var object = { a: { b: { c: 3 } }, d: 4 };

console.log(getKeys(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```